# CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary outputs a string rather than "binary"

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm using this simple method to save a string:

```
public static async void SaveStringAsync(string stringData, string fileName)
{
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(stringData, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
}
```

When I open the saved file in notepad, I see the string in full glory. I was under the impression that saving as binary would mean that if I open the file in notepad, all I'll see is garbage and random characters.

I wanted to see some very light obfuscation for what I am saving *even though it is not a security requirement* (no passwords, sensitive data being saved of any kind). Is there no way to write out a file that will show nonsense rather than a pure string?

Comment: There's probably some built-in tool, though you could do it yourself easily enough.  ConvertStringToBinary isn't it; the [only three encodings available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.binarystringencoding.aspx) are all text encodings.

Comment: So what exactly is meant by "convert to binary" here then?

Comment: The function converts a string into a binary representation of that string, i.e., an implementation-independent set of bytes, suitable to pass to an encryption function, save in a file, or transmit over a network.  (In practice, of course, the string was *already* stored in a binary representation, but that is an implementation detail which is abstracted away by the String class.  The conversion function removes the abstraction, as well as converting from an unspecified encoding chosen by the implementation to a specific encoding chosen by the programmer.)

Comment: I see. So if I understood you correctly, the "garbage" that I see opening "binary" files from other apps is just a different encoding set?

Comment: If the data represents text, but notepad does not display the text correctly, it might be in a non-standard encoding, or it might be compressed, obfuscated, or otherwise modified.  (Microsoft Office documents, for example, are compressed.)  You should note that "binary" is indeed sometimes informally used to mean "not text" but this depends on the context; it's a bit like the way the word "animal" is sometimes informally used to mean "not human" even though humans are in fact animals.